# Get related row based on two MAX Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, greatest-n-per-group, max

I bumped into a use case where I wanted to write a SQL query to retrieve a row based on 2 MAX values of the table. I tried a couple of combinations but no luck as of yet. Here's a sample table and the requirement:

```
Index   cardCode    updateDate  updateTS    unitValue
1       sf-001      2018/1/1    1122        $12 
2       sf-001      2018/2/19   7788        $4 
3       sf-002      2018/1/2    2233        $56 
4       sf-003      2018/3/14   3344        $77 
5       sf-003      2018/3/14   4455        $51 
6       sf-003      2018/3/2    6677        $88 
7       sf-004      2018/11/11  8880        $73
```

The SQL query should return the rows with MAX `updateDate` per `cardCode`. E.g. for "sf-001" it should return row 2 (`unitValue` of $4). If it has two or more identical `updateDate`s then it should check for the MAX `updateTS`. E.g. for "sf-003" it should return row 5 (`unitValue` of $51). So the query should result in the following output:

```
Index   cardCode    updateDate  updateTS    unitValue
1       sf-001      2018/2/19   7788        $4 
2       sf-002      2018/1/2    2233        $56 
3       sf-003      2018/3/14   4455        $51 
4       sf-004      2018/11/11  8880        $73
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for subquery/CTE:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cardCode 
                           ORDER BY updateDate DESC, updateTS DESC);
```

Comment: There's no need not to use a subquery/CTE either. This will involve a full sort of all qualifying rows even if an index exists that supports the partition and order by. e.g. as https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89feb0836b29c2289ce45a71a2ca8b0d

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear case to use cte and window functions, please read about them a little. I assume you do not have too much data, so this code is efficient

```
;with cte
    as (select Index, cardCode, updateDate, updateTS, unitValue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cardCode ORDER BY updateDate DESC, updateTS DESC) as rn
    from YourTable)
    select Index, cardCode, updateDate, updateTS, unitValue
    from cte
    where rn = 1
```

Comment: Update: Excellent. I have no idea how it works. Because my background is purely in to CRM. However the results come like a charm. Quick question: I'm using this query in a integration tool. Hope there won't be any implications. Thoughts?